# How to use xml namespace wildcard in SQL (multiple xml files in table with different namespace url)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a SQL filetable where multiple xml files are stored for use in SQL.
The content of the xml files is out of my control. I just need to use them as input for my table. 
All xml files have the same structure/setup. The only issue is that I just realized that some of those xml files have a different namespace url (hence those returned NULL in my table).

I'm using the xml files to create a table, where the key's from the xml's are returned as column and the attributes as value in the rows. Every xml is returned as row.

So the issue I came across now, is that for all xml's with a (slightly) different namespace, the entire row returns NULL.

The namespaces used are:
http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2016/1/0/0
and
http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2017/1/0/0

The query I used:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2016/1/0/0' AS ns2) -- Pull namespaces for NS2
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT [name]
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField[@key="SbiBusinessCode"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS SBI
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField[@key="FinancialYear"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS FY
    from dbo.XBRLft t -- filestream table
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(t.[file_stream] AS XML)) A(xbrl) -- convert filestream into xml.
    CROSS APPLY xbrl.nodes('/opendata') x(l) 
    where x.l.exist('./*/@key')=1 
    ) p
```

This returns the table with values for only the first namespace (since used in the query), but every row based on an xml which has the second namespace returns null.

So I've tried to use a wildcard instead of the namespace, but that only returns errors.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT [name]
    -- Putting all key's as columns and showing the attribute value in row.
    ,x.l.value('(//*:ns2:opendataField[@key="FinancialYear"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS FY
    from dbo.XBRLft t -- filestream table
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(t.[file_stream] AS XML)) A(xbrl) -- 
    CROSS APPLY xbrl.nodes('//*:opendata') x(l) -- 
    where x.l.exist('./*/@key')=1 -- 
    ) p
```

There are many more keys in the query, but left those out for this example.

Any idea's how I can make this work by either applying 2 namespace url's or a fix for the wildcard?

UPDATE

These are 2 examples (1 of each XML with the different namespace). I'm not sure that I can use COALESCE, because both XML versions use ns2 throughout the xml (and I need to add the entire path in the query to obtain the different keys/values because the xml's are layered).

XML 1:

```
<opendata xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2016/1/0/0">
  <ns2:opendataField key="DocumentAdoptionDate" value="2017-08-27" />
  <ns2:opendataField key="FinancialYear" value="2016" />
  <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheet">
    <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResultsTitle">
      <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResults" value="Na" />
    </ns2:opendataField>
    <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetTitle">
      <ns2:opendataField key="Assets" value="548985">
        <ns2:opendataField key="AssetsNoncurrent" value="447571">
          <ns2:opendataField key="PropertyPlantEquipment" value="208215" />
          <ns2:opendataField key="FinancialAssets" value="239355" />
        </ns2:opendataField>
        <ns2:opendataField key="AssetsCurrent" value="101414">
          <ns2:opendataField key="Receivables" value="68895" />
          <ns2:opendataField key="CashAndCashEquivalents" value="32519" />
        </ns2:opendataField>
      </ns2:opendataField>
etc etc
```

XML2

```
<opendata xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.kvk.nl/xb/query/service/2017/1/0/0">
  <ns2:opendataField key="DocumentAdoptionDate" value="2019-03-11" />
  <ns2:opendataField key="FinancialYear" value="2017" />
  <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheet">
    <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResultsTitle">
      <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetBeforeAfterAppropriationResults" value="Na" />
    </ns2:opendataField>
    <ns2:opendataField key="BalanceSheetTitle">
      <ns2:opendataField key="Assets" value="184535">
        <ns2:opendataField key="AssetsCurrent" value="184535">
          <ns2:opendataField key="AssetsCurrentOther" value="184535" />
        </ns2:opendataField>
      </ns2:opendataField>
etc etc
```

So to obtain the key's and values that I need the query looks like this:

```
 SELECT [name]
    -- Putting all key's as columns and showing the attribute value in row.
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField[@key="SbiBusinessCode"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS SBI
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField[@key="FinancialYear"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS FY
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField[@key="Assets"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Assets
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField[@key="AssetsNoncurrent"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS AssetsNoncurrent
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField[@key="IntangibleAssets"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS IntangibleAssets
    ,x.l.value('(ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField/ns2:opendataField[@key="PropertyPlantEquipment"]/@value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS PropertyPlantEquipment
```

I'm not sure how to apply your COALESCE example here, since both XML types have ns2 in there, and I need the entire path..

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are needed to avoid ambiguity between equal names. Using a wildcard can be very dangerous in this point of view and might lead to unexpected results...

Try this:

A dummy table with some test data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('<root xmlns="blah1">
 <test>Test in 1</test>
 </root>'),
('<root xmlns="blah2">
 <test>Test in 2</test>
 </root>');
```

-- This is your problem: We define the default namespace, which will work with case 1 only:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'blah1')
SELECT t.id
      ,t.YourXml.value('(/root/test/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ContentOfTest
FROM @tbl t;
```

--But we can use two prefixed namespaces and use COALESCE to return the one which returns a value:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('blah1' AS ns1
                  ,'blah2' AS ns2)
SELECT t.id
      ,COALESCE(
       t.YourXml.value('(/ns1:root/ns1:test/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') 
      ,t.YourXml.value('(/ns2:root/ns2:test/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') 
       ) AS ContentOfTest
FROM @tbl t
```

--This was the way to use a wildcard, if you can be sure, that this will not lead into ambiguity:

```
SELECT t.id
      ,t.YourXml.value('(/*:root/*:test/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ContentOfTest
FROM @tbl t
```

Comment: I truly appreciate the step-by-step.   EXCEPTIONAL ANSWER!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and feedback. 
Apologies for my delayed response, I was on holiday.

I believe COALESCE would be a great idea. However I'm not sure it would work with the XML's I need to use. I've updated my initial question to include examples of the 2 XML versions.

Comment: @jmhrijdt You are not bound to the prefixes. In fact you can use any prefix you like. Just use `AS ns1` for the one and `AS ns2` for the other one and then use them consistently in your XPath. Hope this helps...

Comment: @Shnugo, so do you mean I would need to alter the XPath for both options?

Comment: @jmhrijdt Exactly. Declare them with *any prefix* and use *this prefix* in the path.

Comment: @Shnugo, Thank you once again! Just tried, and this works like a charm.